# Can the number of parameters determined by templates in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

Lets say, i have a class like this:

```
template<unsigned int L,class base>
class CLASS
{
public:
    base data[L];
    CLASS(base _data[L])
    {
        for (int i=0;i<L;i++)
            data[i] = _data[i];
    }
    ...
}
```

so this is valid:

```
int d[4] = {1,2,3,4};
CLASS<int> cls1(d);
```

is there a way to make a constructor for CLASS
what takes L base(s)?
So this would be valid:

```
CLASS<double> cls2(0.0,0.2,0.3);
```

ui: I don't want to use c++11 unless it is necessary,

Edit: So my question would be: Can it be done WITHOUT c++11 ?

Comment: Note: `CLASS(base _data[L])` decays to (is equivalent to) `CLASS(base* _data)`. You probably want to use `CLASS(base const (&_data)[L])`.

Comment: In C++03, you could mimic variadic templates by manually providing a set of overloaded constructors with 1,2,...,N arguments. With an `enable_if` trick you could make viable only the constructor with exactly `L` arguments. E.g. `CLASS(base const& p0, base const& p1, unique_t = typename enable_if<L==2, unique_t>::type())`